# html AgilityPack XPath C# .net 4

Tags: xml, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have to define xpath to access second span text to parse the following name-value html structure (see below) loaded to AgilityPack document. I would to do the folowing query using xpath and C#:

```
var valueSpan = doc.SelectNodes("//div[@class='container']/div[@class='value2' and ???]/span[2]");
```

Question: I can't write xpath selector for "second matched div with class=="value2". Is it possible to select second "value2" div using xpath or it should be done by indexing childs of "container" node (actual sibling index of "value2" may vary)?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="value1">
    <span class="name">Title 1</span>
    <span class="value">some value</span>
  </div>
  <div class="value2">
    <span class="name">Title 2.1</span>
    <span class="value">some value</span>
  </div>
  <div class="value2">
    <span class="name">Title 2.2</span>
    <span class="value">some value</span>
  </div>
  <div class="value3">
    <span class="name">Title 3</span>
    <span class="value">some value</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What text are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I am looking for "some value" (I would like to separate "some value" from "Title 2.1" and "some value" from "Title 2.2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
//div[@class='container']/div[@class='value2'][2]
```